# Airflow 2 / Docker: adding custom network in docker-compose.yml fails

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, airflow

I have installed airflow 2.0.2 using docker-compose as described under https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/start/docker.html. The used docker-compose.yml can be found here: https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.0.2/docker-compose.yaml

I want to execute a DAG which downloads some data via an API and sends it into a Kafka server which is running in yet another docker container (defined in another docker-compose pipeline). So far (without using airflow), I used a custom docker network for the kafka / zookeper containers; that's why I also want to add the airflow docker containers to this network.

Thus, I add the following to the airflow's docker-compose.yml:

```
networks:
  app-tier:
    driver: bridge
    name: app-tier
```

Additionally, I include the `networks` argument to `x-airflow-common`, like so:

```
version: '3'
x-airflow-common:
  &airflow-common
  build: .
  image: ${AIRFLOW_IMAGE_NAME:-apache/airflow:2.0.2}
  environment:
    &airflow-common-env
    AIRFLOW__CORE__EXECUTOR: CeleryExecutor
    AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN: postgresql+psycopg2://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__RESULT_BACKEND: db+postgresql://airflow:airflow@postgres/airflow
    AIRFLOW__CELERY__BROKER_URL: redis://:@redis:6379/0
    AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY: ''
    AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__CORE__LOAD_EXAMPLES: 'false'
    AIRFLOW__API__AUTH_BACKEND: 'airflow.api.auth.backend.basic_auth'
  volumes:
    - ./dags:/opt/airflow/dags
    - ./logs:/opt/airflow/logs
    - ./plugins:/opt/airflow/plugins
  user: "${AIRFLOW_UID:-50000}:${AIRFLOW_GID:-50000}"
  depends_on:
    redis:
      condition: service_healthy
    postgres:
      condition: service_healthy
  networks:
    - app-tier
```

However, when starting my docker-compose pipeline, the health checks of all containers excluding Postgres and Redis (worker, webserver, flower, scheduler) fail, with the following message:

> daniel@Yoga:~/Schreibtisch/Projekte/db/airflow_neu$ docker logs airflowWorker
> BACKEND=postgresql+psycopg2 DB_HOST=postgres
>
> DB_PORT=5432 .................... ERROR! Maximum number of retries
> (20) reached.
>
> Last check result: $ run_nc 'postgres' '5432' Traceback (most recent
> call last):   File "", line 1, in  socket.gaierror:
> [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution Can't parse  as an IP
> address

I interpret this as the Postgres database not being reachable anymore, but I don't know how to resolve this.

- Is my approach correct to add the airflow containers to an existing network?
- How can I resolve the failing health checks?

Comment: How is this question related to programming? It might be better suited for [DevOps](https://devops.stackexchange.com/) or [SF]. --- Please read: [Can I ask only one question per post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/222735/can-i-ask-only-one-question-per-post)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it by including the `external` tag:

```
networks:
  default:
    external: true
    name: app-tier
```